# How to get rid of special characters while extracting data from web?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am extracting data from the website and it has an entry that contains a special character i.e. `Comfort Inn And Suites�? Blazing Stump`. When I try to extract it, it throws an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 638, in _tick
    taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 484, in _oneWorkUnit
    result = next(self._iterator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
    work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
    yield it.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\contrib\spidermiddleware\offsite.py", line 24, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\contrib\spidermiddleware\referer.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\contrib\spidermiddleware\urllength.py", line 32, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\contrib\spidermiddleware\depth.py", line 48, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "E:\Scrapy projects\emedia\emedia\spiders\test_spider.py", line 46, in parse
    print repr(business.select('a[@class="name"]/text()').extract()[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\selector\lxmlsel.py", line 51, in select
    result = self.xpathev(xpath)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 318, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:145954)

  File "xpath.pxi", line 241, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:144987)

  File "extensions.pxi", line 621, in lxml.etree._unwrapXPathObject (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:139973)

  File "extensions.pxi", line 655, in lxml.etree._createNodeSetResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:140328)

  File "extensions.pxi", line 676, in lxml.etree._unpackNodeSetEntry (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:140524)

  File "extensions.pxi", line 784, in lxml.etree._buildElementStringResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:141695)

  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1373, in lxml.etree.funicode (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:26255)

exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 22: invalid continuation byte
```

I have tried a lot of different things after searching on the web such as `decode('utf-8')`, `unicodedata.normalize('NFC',business.select('a[@class="name"]/text()').extract()[0])` but the problem persists?

The source URL is "http://www.truelocal.com.au/find/hotels/97/" and on this page it is fourth entry which I am talking about.

Comment: That's a Mojibake in the original data that cannot be repaired. It's a question of Garbage In, and you cannot but keep it around as Garbage.

Comment: what is the convenient way to get rid of it then??

Comment: Mojibake _can_ be fixed via SQL.

Answer (score 4):

You have a bad [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in the original webpage, 
probably due to bad handling of Unicode in the data entry somewhere. The actual UTF-8 bytes in the source are `C3 3F C2 A0` when expressed in hexadecimal.

I **think** it was once a [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://codepoints.net/U+00A0). Encoded to UTF-8 that becomes `C2 A0`, interpret *that* as Latin-1 instead then encode to UTF-8 again becomes `C3 82 C2 A0`, but `82` is a control character if interpreted as Latin-1 again so that was substituted by a `?` question mark, hex `3F` when encoded.

When you follow the link to the [detail page for that venue](http://www.truelocal.com.au/business/comfort-inn-and-suitesaaaa-blazing-stump/wodonga) then you get a different Mojibake for the same name: `Comfort Inn And SuitesÃ‚Â Blazing Stump`, giving us the Unicode characters U+00C3, U+201A, U+00C2 a `&nbsp;` HTML entity, or unicode character U+00A0 again. Encode that as [Windows Codepage 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (a superset of Latin-1) and you get `C3 82 C2 A0` again.

You can only get rid of it by targeting this directly in the source of the page

```
pagesource.replace('\xc3?\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0')
```

This 'repairs' the data by substituting the train wreck with the original intended UTF-8 bytes.

If you have a scrapy `Response` object, replace the body:

```
body = response.body.replace('\xc3?\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0')
response = response.replace(body=body)
```

Comment: That being said, it is worst one you follow the link on the original site: `SuitesÃ‚Â Blazing` (`53 75 69 74 65 73 [c3 83 e2 80 9a c3 82  c2 a0] 42 6c 61 7a 69 6e 67`). Seems like multiple encoding maybe?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: That confirms it is a non-breaking space, actually. That's a [U+201A SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+201a) in the middle. In Windows Codepage 1252 that is hex `82`.

Comment: Maybe ',<NSBP><LF><LF>' (`c2 a0 0a 0a`) encoded *twice* from Windows CP-1252 to UTF-8 ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: no, just a single `<NBSP>`; try `u'\xc3\u201a\xc2\xa0'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` (although `cp1252` would work for the second `latin1` too).

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: where `u'\xc3\u201a\xc2\xa0'` is the result of decoding the UTF-8 HTML source to Unicode and replacing the `&nbsp;` with `\x0a`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried your solution but it is not working and giving me the same problem

Comment: @MughalWalana: what is the full traceback of your original error (please add that to your question post).

Comment: @MughalWalana: also, what is does `print repr(value_you_need_to_repair)` show? That'll show me the exact contents as well as the type of the object.

Comment: I'm sorry to hijack this comment, but in this case I just *have* to tip my hat to @MartijnPieters. That's some really nice detective work you have done there!

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Editing Done. and also it does not print anything on the suggested print statement . However for other names successfully coming it just prints their unicode representation such as u'Wompoo Cottage'

Comment: @MughalWalana: ah! AH! Both BeautifulSoup and my browser 'repaired' the content; the error is in the UTF-8 encoding of the page.

Comment: Off course it is the problem in utf-8. How it can be corrected programmatically

Comment: @MughalWalana: `lxml` on the other hand choked on the invalid UTF-8 bytes in the source. How does scrapy give you the source, or does it give you the `lxml` parse tree here?

Comment: it gives us basically htmlxpathselector through which we can extract elements of webpage by their DOM ids

Comment: @MughalWalana: I'll try and figure out how to get at the raw bytes in the Scrapy response. Can you show us a little more context for the selection line? I'd like to see what object you have (I am assuming that `business` is a `HtmlResponse` object perhaps?).

Comment: hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    businesses = hxs.select('//div[@class="media-content"]/div[@class="media"]/div[@class="media-content"]')

we get list of all matching nodes in business and then loop through it for getting data as mentioned in my above question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "replace" to fix Mojibake, fix the database and the code that caused the Mojibake.

But first you need to determine whether it is simply Mojibake or "double-encoding".  With a `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` determine whether a single character turned into 2-4 bytes (Mojibake) or 4-6 bytes (double encoding).  Examples:

```
`é` (as utf8) should come back `C3A9`, but instead shows `C383C2A9`
The Emoji `` should come back `F09F91BD`, but comes back `C3B0C5B8E28098C2BD`
```

Review "Mojibake" and "double encoding" [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Then the database fixes are discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases) :

- CHARACTER SET latin1, but have utf8 bytes in it; leave bytes alone while fixing charset:

First, lets assume you have this declaration for tbl.col:

```
col VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
```

Then to convert the column without changing the bytes via this 2-step ALTER:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(111) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL;
```

Note: If you start with `TEXT`, use `BLOB` as the intermediate definition. (This is the "2-step ALTER, as discussed elsewhere.) (Be sure to keep the other specifications the same - VARCHAR, NOT NULL, etc.)

- `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` with double-encoding:
  `UPDATE tbl SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(col USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);`
- `CHARACTER SET latin1` with double-encoding: Do the 2-step ALTER, then fix the double-encoding.