# php query not using UTF-8 charset

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am getting my urls and titles from a post's content, but the titles no longer seem to be UTF-8 and include some funky characters such as "Â" when I echo the result. Any idea why the correct charset isn't being used? My headers do use the right metadata.

I tried some of the solutions on here, but none seems to work so I thought I'd add my code below - just in case I'm missing something.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "xxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);


$post_id = 228;

$content_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $content);

$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');


$counter = 0;
foreach ($links as $link){

$href = $link->getAttribute('href');
$avoid  = array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpeg');

if ($href == str_replace($avoid, '', $href)) {

$title = $link->nodeValue;
$title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');



$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_urls_download (title, url) VALUES ('$title', '$href')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
$counter++;
echo "Entry" . $counter . ": $title" . "<br>";

} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

}

}
```

Updated Echo string - changed this after I initially uploaded the code. I have already tried the solutions in the other posts and was not successful.

Comment: Because you're not setting your *database connection encoding*?!

Comment: hmm, not really. I see what you are getting at, but I am just echoing the $title value at on the screen, so the database connection does not get involved (yet)

Comment: You are echoing what where exactly? What encoding is the content in?

Comment: ah my bad, I updated my code after posting this. I have now added the updated echo code where it just echos the `$title`. I have also added `$title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`  but no success. the original content is in utf-8.

Comment: Show `bin2hex($title)` and what you expect the title to look like.

Comment: lot's of lines - but this is one with the funky character: `5472616e737665727365204162646f6d696e6973c382c2a02854564129`

Comment: This is the current title `Transverse AbdominisÂ (TVA)`
but it should be `Transverse Abdominis (TVA)`

Comment: You will have to trace that back a bit more to find the source of that byte sequence. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25502632/476.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'n the meantime, I'll use `$titles = str_replace("Â","",$title);`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't answer my own question as it's closed - but this worked for me `$title = utf8_decode($title);`

Comment: Do not use any form of encode/decode; 2 wrongs may appear to make a right, but really they add to the mess.

Comment: @RickJames yeah that's true - I'll use your answer and go through it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have "double-encoding".  What you expected was

```
Transverse Abdominis (TVA)
```

But what you have for the space before the parenthesis is a special space that probably came from Microsoft Word, then got converted to utf8 twice. In hex: `A0` -> `c2a0` -> `c382c2a0`.

Yes, the link to "utf8 all the way through" would ultimately provide the fix, but I think you need more help.

The `A0` was converted from latin1 to utf8, then treating those bytes as if they were latin1 and repeating the conversion.

The connection provide the client's encoding via `mysqli_obj->set_charset('utf8')` (or similar).

Then the column in the table should be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` (or utf8).  Verify with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (It is probably latin1 currently.)

HTML should start with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.

[Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I managed to get it to work when my question was locked, but is good to understand what's happened and why it's happened. Thanks.

Comment: @Remco - I hope you did not fix it with `str_replace`; that will fix only the one case; other cases may show up with different messes.

Comment: Oh no, I must say that I was tempted, but I realised that it would have been a risky and messy "fix" `$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'. $content);` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to set the utf8 charset on the connection?

`$conn->set_charset('utf8');`

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: This didn't work for me on the load content, but setting it on the connection is a good one. Didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I had before the same situation and changing the connection encoding worked well for me.